# Visual Studio 2013 unable to create diagnostic report

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, profiling

I have a 64 bit project in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. When I profile it with Visual Studio's built in cpu profiler, it collects the data fine. But when I stop the profiler it says: 'Microsoft Visual Studio was unable to create a diagnostics report.'

The output window shows this:

```
Profiling of '[Project name]' started.
[Project name] has exited.
Profiling of '[Project name]' stopped.
Diagnostics session stopped with errors.

An error occurred opening '%temp%\BD371444-95DE-4EF8-9433-A9D00C516579'. The formatting of the file is not supported by this version of Visual Studio. Please try again with a different file or a different version of Visual Studio.
```

In the folder listed, there are .etl files that can be opened with the Windows Performance Analyzer with no error.

I have tried repairing Visual Studio to no effect.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It seems it happened after I made a "repair" on my Visual Studio, but it may be unrelated.

I didn't find a real solution to the problem, but I have found a workaround that worked for me :

1. Start the process unattached (Ctrl+F5)
2. Go to the menu ANALYSE > Profiler > Attach/Detach
3. When stopping, it worked

I have no idea why, but it works for me since I don't use it very often.

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me (VS 2015 on Windows 10) was running VS as administrator